# Indefinitely retain release and build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following setting under 'Release Retention'

[image]

I would like to know two things:

1. If I retain a release and it's build indefinitely from the Release pipeline, does it mean that I can retain it longer than the default of 365 days shown below?

[image]

2. I would also like to know what is the Azure DevOps action if I have the 26th release and build that I want to retain indefinitely?

In short, I am little confused on the "Retain Indefinitely" vs the 365 days and 25 builds setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I retain a release and it's build indefinitely from the Release pipeline, does it mean that I can retain it longer than the default of 365 days shown below?

Yes. You are right. If you use the `Retain indefinitely` option,  the release will keep forever(irrespective of the number of days specified).

> I would also like to know what is the Azure DevOps action if I have the 26th release and build that I want to retain indefinitely?

You just need to find the 26th release and set the `Retain indefinitely` option. Then the release will retain indefinitely and the related build will also be retained.

> "Retain Indefinitely" vs the 365 days and 25 builds setting

The `Retain Indefinitely` option is used to keep the target release forever. It will not be affected by the retention policy.

For `Days to retain a release   365` and `Minimum releases to keep  25`, the `Days to retain a release` and `Minimum releases to keep` are equals two fields. and the 365 and 25 are the maximum value of these two fields.

These two fields are used for the retention policy in Release -> Stage -> Retention.

[image]

Each stage has a different rentention policy. And the max value is 365 and 25. You could set them for every stages.

Here is [a doc about release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#release), you could refer to it.